Creating rows based on another table, but require the newly inserted UUID to be set on the parent table
INSERT INTO inventory
(
   id,
   product_sku
)

SELECT 
    gen_random_uuid(),
    p.sku
FROM products p
WHERE 
  p.id NOT IN (SELECT id from products where inventory_id IS NULL)

This query above works fine, but the problem is I need to update each product record with:
products.inventory_id = 123

i.e. the newly inserted UUID value has to be set on the product table.
Is it possible to do this in a single update operation or I have to do this in a secondary update statement somehow?

It sounds like a task for an insert..returning. Problem is, you can't use it to return anything that's not a literal or one of the fields being inserted - you'd lose id:
WITH inserted AS (
    INSERT INTO inventory AS i (id,product_sku)
    SELECT gen_random_uuid() as gen_uuid,
           products.sku
    FROM products
    RETURNING products.id--this isn't allowed
)--you can only return fields of the target `inventory` table, or constants
UPDATE products 
SET inventory_id=inserted.gen_uuid
FROM inserted 
WHERE products.id=inserted.id;

To work around that,
you can move the insert payload one CTE up, constructing a table that has both what you want to insert into inventory as well as the id you want to use when you update products. Then use that CTE twice, as a source for both:
demo at db<>fiddle
WITH to_insert AS
(   SELECT p.id,
           gen_random_uuid() as gen_uuid,
           p.sku
    FROM products AS p
    WHERE inventory_id IS NOT NULL)
,inserted AS (
    INSERT INTO inventory AS i (id,product_sku)
    SELECT gen_uuid, sku
    FROM to_insert)
UPDATE products 
SET inventory_id=to_insert.gen_uuid
FROM to_insert
WHERE products.id=to_insert.id;


shouldn't the SET inventory_id be using the 'inserted' table?

Yes and no. Yes, because you ultimately want to use the gen_uuid from what you just inserted, which sound like a task for a insert..returning clause. Problem is, you can't do returning to_insert.id in there, because id isn't among the fields that are being inserted. So you need to move it CTE up, constructing a table that has both what you want to insert into inventory as well as the id you want to use when you update products. I just realised I left the misleading returning thing in, even though that won't work - sorry for that.

since we created the UUID it is fine, but if the db created the id then its required actually...

@Blankman In both cases the db creates the uuid, and it's the same one that gets re-used for both the insert and the update, if that's what you mean. If not, please add an example and explain what exactly you're trying to achieve/avoid and I'll take a look
